# Rational symmetric polynomial in the roots of an integer polynomial is rational

Tags: polynomials, roots

I'm reading a book on trigonometric series, and the author uses the following result in a proof:

Let $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial (with integers coefficients) of degree $n>0$, and let $S\in\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a symmetric polynomial.

Let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ be the roots of $f$. Then $S(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Is there an elementary proof of this fact? I've tried writing

$$\alpha_k=\sum_{i\neq k}a_i\alpha_k^i, \ 1\le k\le n$$

So

$$S(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)=S\left(\sum_{i\neq 1}a_i\alpha_1^i,\dots,\sum_{i\neq n}a_i\alpha_n^i\right)$$

which does not seem too useful. Also, by the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, it would suffice to show the claim for elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: The elementary symmetric polynomials in the roots are the coefficients of $f$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you very much! Just to clarify, if $f$ were monic, by Vieta's formulas I could conclude that $S(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is actually an integer, right?

Comment: Yes, provided that $S \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots x_n]$ (in addition to being symmetric).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right, of course. If you'd like to add an answer, I'll accept it.